# How can I compile and run the attached react web application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, package.json

I'm new to node and npm. I've been trying to compile this Medication reminder app I found on GitHub (https://github.com/marshallmurphy/Web-Apps/tree/master/Medication%20Reminder%20React%20App) but npm keeps producing errors. I've tried "npm start" and running "webpack" but no luck. How can I compile and run this file in the terminal?

I get the following error when I run npm start:

```
Dantes-MBP:Medication Reminder React App dantegreyson$ npm start

> medication-reminder-app@1.0.0 start /Users/dantegreyson/Desktop/Medication Reminder React App
> webpack-dev-server

sh: webpack-dev-server: command not found

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! medication-reminder-app@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the medication-reminder-app@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the medication-reminder-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs medication-reminder-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls medication-reminder-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/dantegreyson/Desktop/Medication Reminder React App/npm-debug.log
```

I tried installing webpack globally as suggested but now gets the following error:

```
Dantes-MBP:Medication Reminder React App dantegreyson$ npm start

> medication-reminder-app@1.0.0 start /Users/dantegreyson/Desktop/Medication Reminder React App
> webpack-dev-server

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'html-webpack-plugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dantegreyson/Desktop/Medication Reminder React App/webpack.config.js:1:87)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! medication-reminder-app@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the medication-reminder-app@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the medication-reminder-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs medication-reminder-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls medication-reminder-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/dantegreyson/Desktop/Medication Reminder React App/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: `npm install` && `npm start`. If it doesnt help. please post the relevant errors

Comment: @TheReason I have the latest version of npm and node installed. However I still receive an error. I have posted the error above.

Comment: I just cloned the repository and did `npm install` and after install finished I did `npm start` It works like charm. node version `4.4.3`. `npm install` installs the necessary packages. I did not install webpack or related packages earlier.

Comment: @SatishPatel After directing to localhost:8080 did the web application work past the first page (Medication Reminder: Get Started)?

Comment: after `npm start` when navigated to `localhost:8080` It renders the medication reminder Get Started.

Comment: @SatishPatel Did the web app work after clicking "Get Started"? Mine doesn't. After inspecting the code on Chrome console I see the following error. index_bundle.js:7810 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null(…)

Comment: try navigating this `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server`  after `npm start` and see if it lists 3 links `index_bindle.js` and `index_bundle` and `index.html`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129516/discussion-between-satish-patel-and-dante-greyson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at *package.json* in script section you will see what it tries to run
`"start": "webpack-dev-server"`. So you should install `webpack-dev-server` globally
`sudo npm install webpack-dev-server -g` should do all magic for you.

*update*

Make sure that you run `npm install` command

Comment: I tried this however I get the error Cannot find module 'html-webpack-plugin'. I have posted this error in detail above.

Comment: @DanteGreyson did you run the command `npm install` ? It should have installed all dependencies

Comment: Yes you are right i tried npm install again and it worked! For some reason dependencies werent installed before. I received the meesage webpack: bundle is now VALID. after running npm start. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: @DanteGreyson by default webpack-dev-server uses 8080 port. try to connect _localhost:8080_

Comment: Yes this works! However the page doesn't go past the first page. But the compilation works nonetheless thank you. Is there a way to run the index.html?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129553/discussion-between-the-reason-and-dante-greyson).